# Anylogic Parameter Variation Experiment output to Excel

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm trying to use parameter variation experiment of Anylogic and export the result "loss" of each run to the corresponding position in the Excel table. However, only a few of the results are successfully exported to the table. The related code and result are shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Yic.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jue8d.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmOYg.png)

I am looking for where it went wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not share the code that is writing the results to Excel which might be the reason for the problem. However, another possibility is that you have to turn off allowing parallel evaluations under ***Advanced***.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I turned off the allowing parallel evaluations and now it works. Thanks!!